# Ошибка при добавлении картинки в проект

Tags: android, vector-drawable

Я добавила в папку *\src\main\res\drawable-v21* изображение Vector Drawable  *ic_menu_calendar_range.xml*, добавила в файл *drawables.xml*:

```
<item name="ic_menu_calendar_range" type="drawable">
@android:drawable/ic_menu_calendar_range
</item>
```

И получаю ошибку:

> Error:(626, 57) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'ic_menu_calendar_range' with value
>   '@android:drawable/ic_menu_calendar_range').

В чём причина ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка исчезла после удаления из *drawables.xml* строки:

```
<item name="ic_menu_calendar_range" type="drawable">
@android:drawable/ic_menu_calendar_range
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что элемента с таким же названием нет в стандартной папке `/drawable`.

Попробуйте скопировать туда это файл или положить какой-то стандартный (или даже пустой), но с таким же именем файл. На этапе релизной сборки приложения IDE напомнит Вам о том, что содержание директорий с ресурсами не одинаково, даже если Вы не используете файлы из них.